# How can I get the tourism bonus for having the same religion as another civilization?

Tags: civilization-5

According to the [Civ5 wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Tourism_(Civ5)#Spreading_Tourism), your civilization gains a 25% (40% with Aesthetics) bonus to tourism to other nations that share the same "majority religion".

**What does it mean for two civilizations to share a majority religion?** Since each city within a civilization can have a different religion, I'm not sure what this entails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each city can have followers of multiple religions; the city's "majority religion" -- the one whose icon shows up next to the city's name -- is determined by which religion has the most followers in said city (assuming they meet a certain minimum threshold related to city population).

In the exact same way, your civilization as a whole will have followers of multiple religions, and one of those will be the majority -- namely, the religion that has the most followers in your civilization. Multiple civilizations can therefore have the same majority religion (i.e. they each have more followers of that religion than any other), and that's what that Tourism bonus is based on.

Comment: At least half of a city's population must follow a religion for the city to be following it, and its icon will appear. Does the civilization's religion work similar or is it really as you say: the religion with the most followers? For example, a pop 7 city requires 4 followers. Your saying that a pop 100 civ I I'll have a majority religion as soon as it gains it's first follower. Doesn't it need 50 followers? Or perhaps 5 of its 10 cities must have hat same religion.

Comment: @DavidHarkness What you say seems to me to be exactly how it *should* be, and maybe that is exactly how it is supposed to work. I just know that I've seen e.g. pop 5 cities having a "majority religion" with only 2 followers, but I've also seen pop 15 cities with no majority religion despite one having 6 followers. Maybe that's a bug (in either the game or my memory), but that's why I hesitate to say that it is strictly a majority. In any case, there definitely *is* a minimum threshold a religion *must* meet to be the "majority religion", whether that's for a city or the civ as a whole.